# HashiCorp Consul vs AWS S3 as backend storage for HashiCorp Vault?

Tags: amazon-s3, consul, hashicorp-vault

I'm doing review now and can't see any disadvantages of using S3 over the Consul for Vault backend storage, i think that even deploying Consul in multiple EC2 scenario would cost more.
For example 10GB of EBS volume cost more than 10GB of S3.
HA? By default S3 is already HA, so no difference there.
S3 would also be more protected from accidental deletion.

Is there any perfomance penalty on mid or big scale environment that S3 would struggle?? 
What else could be the differentiation factor? Some feature that i have overlooked? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From AWS documentation: "Amazon S3 automatically scales to high request rates. For example, your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and 5,500 GET requests per second per prefix in a bucket. There are no limits to the number of prefixes in a bucket. It is simple to increase your read or write performance exponentially. For example, if you create 10 prefixes in an Amazon S3 bucket to parallelize reads, you could scale your read performance to 55,000 read requests per second."

So, basically S3 has limit and doesn't, we can scale up using diff buckets.

Comment: What kind of secrets are you putting in there?  I wouldn't imagine that you'd break the bank on 1GB of storage space, let alone 10GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this question>

1. S3 offers "4 nines" of availability or 99,99%
   four nines or 99.99% availability allows 52 minutes, 36 seconds downtime per year.

Consul can achieve greater HA.

2. The Vault storage engine doesn't allow for Vault HA (native Vault HA, not keepalive) with S3. You can only run a single Vault server when using the S3 backend.
3. If you want to upgrade to Vault Enterprise, HashiCorp is giving this only with Consul, so there is no option with S3.